# Parsing web pages via C#, XmlDocument.LoadXml

Tags: c#, parsing, web, xmldocument

I'm trying to download a web page and parse it. I need to reach every node of html document. So I used WebClient to download, which works perfectly. Then I use following code segment to parse the document:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();

 Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~bil339/");
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
 string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

 data.Close();
 reader.Close();
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.loadXml(xml);
```

In last line, program waits for some time, then crashes. It says there are errors in HTML code, this wasn't expected, that shouldn't be here, etc. 
Any suggestions to fix this? Other techniques to parse HTML code are welcome (In C#, of course.)

Comment: loadxml expects a xml document, if it is html page, it will throw exception

Comment: some pages adhering to xhtml can be parsed with XML reader, but to parse _any_ html page you would have to use special html parser.

Comment: @kashif Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=VS.85).aspx
Denis You're right, this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse HTML.  Well-formed HTML is not XML and can't be parsed as such.  For instance, it lacks the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` preamble that all XML files require.  The HTML Agility Pack is more forgiving.